# Pseudo random number generator with > 64 bit seed for a 52 card deck shuffle

Tags: random, shuffle

While writing a card shuffling algorithm I realized that there are 52! ~= 2^225 possible shuffles that can occur. Given this, it seems to me that any shuffling algorithm based on a PRNG with a standard 32 bit or 64 bit seed would only be capable of producing a subset of all possible shuffles. Since my platform only has a 32 bit seeded PRNG (just the POSIX srandom()/random() functions), I was wondering if there is any way to creatively use this to create a shuffling algorithm capable of producing any result. If not, does anyone know of a PRNG algorithm capable of using a seed which is a composite of several 32 bit integers which I could implement myself?

Comment: There are many RNGs with internal states >226 bits. Probably the most popular are Mersenne Twister and Marsaglia xorshift+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve your problem using the current random number generator, you just have to find a way to divide the parameter space of all possible card shuffles into groups.

For example, if you had a random seed that could only be 1 through 4, but a parameter space that had 12 possible permutations, you would solve using two random seeds:

(seed1) defines which parameter group you were in (1-4,5-8, or 9-12)
(seed2) defines which element is your final result

(The parameter set does not have to be an even multiple of the seed size for this to work.)

I used this method for very-large complexity problems in solid-state physics modeling. This is a rigorous mathematical solution, however it may not be the most elegant software solution. Good luck to you.

Comment: Maybe a complete explanation is too long, but I am curious.  Why does your solution work?  How does your solution differ from the false solution of generating pairs of random numbers from the same generator?  Using two different seeds, after all, does not make the generator any less deterministic, does it?  (I expect that you are right, but I am interested to learn why.)

Comment: Well, in physics the parameter space of a problem was easy to divide into groups. In your case, perhaps you would divide each individual card shuffle option by cases where: card 1 is not permuted, card 2 is not permuted, etc. Then you generate one random number for which card is not permuted, and then a real random number for which specific permutation in that group you want.
I do not believe this makes the random generate any more or less deterministic. And... if it does, that would be important for me to learn.

Comment: So I guess this is possible in principle then. I'll have to think about how this might actually be implemented for the problems of shuffling card though.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  If on Linux, */dev/urandom* or even */dev/random* might suit.  These devices rely on an "entropy pool," fed by the timing of asynchronous hardware events.

However, also investigate the *mrand48()* family of functions, presented in *cstdlib* or *stdlib.h,* whether or not on Linux.  That gets you 48 bits, which is closer to what you want.

Good luck.